# discord.js - MessageCollector won't end

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

The collector won't end, even if there is time set to 1.

```
const filter = msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id;

const collector = new MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
    max: 3,
    time: 5000,
})

collector.on('collect', collector => {
    console.log(`${collector.content}`)
})

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`${collected.size}`)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor takes arguments `(channel, options)` and not `(channel, filter, options)`. `filter` should be part of the `options` object. See [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector).

Right now you are passing the `filter` function *instead* of an `options` object, followed by what *should* be an `options` object but is actually just an ignored superfluous third argument.

This is the correct way:

```js
const collector = new MessageCollector(message.channel, {
    filter,
    max: 3,
    time: 5000
})
```